# Using an ajax-based FilteringSelect with dgrid

Tags: ajax, dojo, dgrid

I'm having an issue with a my current dgrid. I have a column which is `dijit/Form/FilteringSelect` with a Ajax-based store. The store works fine for searching and populating, but, when I open a page with the dgrid store having a couple of rows already I face a problem. Only the last FilteringSelect triggers the edit event and fires the XHR request.

For example, if the Grid store has 4 items, so it will have 4 rows, only the FilteringSelect of the last row will go to the server to get the display value.

I'm a bit lost, any help?

Comment: post some code , so we can help !

Comment: yes, you need to post the code so that someone can identify the issue and guide you

Comment: I'm creating a JSFiddle and will edit as soon as it is done